# How to troubleshoot slow read/write times from a multifunction printer/scanner's SD card?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, printer, sd-card, scanner

I have been trying to help a friend diagnose a problem with their technology.

On their WiFi network, they have an Epson WiFi printer/scanner and several Windows 7 SP1 systems.  The printer/scanner has an SD card slot to store the scans.

Their WiFi network works well.  The speeds are within the appropriate range.  However, accessing the files on the printer/scanner's SD card slot is **amazingly slow**.

What steps can I take to diagnose this problem, and hopefully fix it?

***What I've tried so far:***

- I took the SD card out of the printer, and inserted it directly into a computer.  Reads and writes to the card were very fast.  This confirms the card is not defective or slow.
- I rebooted the printer/scanner, the router, and all the systems on the network.  Doing this did not improve the situation.
- I reformatted the SD card.  No effect.
- I tried another SD card.  No effect.
- I knew *reading* from the printer/scanner's SD card over their network was very slow, but I was not sure about writing.  So I tried writing to the SD card over the network, and it was even slower than reading.  Simply deleting 100 files took over 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with that device but if it acting like my Garmin Nuvi GPS I feel ur pain. I may just be the way the device works and I don't know what the Garmin is doing that should take so long.
I would expect writes to be slower than reads. U might want to load up a copy of Linux and see if it is related to windows or not.